# Parse value from column and insert into new table in T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, charindex

I have a column that I need to parse and insert into a new table. I've come extremely close to getting the data I need but I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Here is the format of the data I need to parse:

Packing Slip #195, UID = Pkg-15094-195

Packing Slip #112, UID = Pkg-41251-241

I just need the packing slip number. It's not always going to be 2 characters of course.

Seems relatively simple, just get the difference of the index of the characters [#] and [,]
Then start at the index of [#] + 1 for a length of [,] - [#] - 1. It's that extra subtraction that is screwing up my syntax:

```
SELECT substring(IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION, 
    CHARINDEX('#', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION) + 1,
    CHARINDEX(',', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('#', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION)
)
AS PKL
FROM MASTER_SCAN_IMAGE
where IMG_SCT_PKEY = '21'
```

That works, but gives me one too many. If I attempt to add another subtraction like so I get a syntax error:

```
SELECT substring(IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION, 
    CHARINDEX('#', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION) + 1,
    (CHARINDEX(',', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('#', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION)) -1
)
AS PKL
FROM MASTER_SCAN_IMAGE
where IMG_SCT_PKEY = '21'

Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

So I figure I should wrap up the length value into a single variable but it's also creating a syntax error:

```
SELECT *
FROM MASTER_SCAN_IMAGE
DECLARE @length int = CHARINDEX(',', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('#', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION);

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION'.
```

In fact I can't seem to assign a variable at all using CHARINDEX, I always end up with the same "invalid column name" error.

```
DECLARE @length bigint = CHARINDEX(',', IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION);

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION'.
```

It's the same whether I use int or bigint which are the two return types that charindex can send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
declare @column varchar(200) = 'Packing Slip #195, UID = Pkg-15094-195'


select RIGHT(LEFT(@column, CHARINDEX(',', @column)-1), CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(LEFT(@column, CHARINDEX(',', @column)-1)))-1)
```

Run the code [here](http://rextester.com/live/TPF20930).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I worded my query poorly and didn't show the full column data I was working with. I just edited my question to reflect the data I have. 

Unfortunately I can't use replace because the end of the data will always have a different number.

Comment: @BrianGe OK, I updated my solution based on the new info you added. Check it out and try it using the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a TVF... consider the following.

Tired of extracting strings, I modifed a parse function to accecpt two **non-like** delimiters.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 (1,'Packing Slip #195, UID = Pkg-15094-195')
,(2,'Packing Slip #112, UID = Pkg-41251-241')
,(3,'Packing Slip #222, UID = Pkg-41251-241 and Slip #999')  -- Notice two Packing Slips

Select A.ID
      ,SlipNr = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.IMG_FILE_DESCRIPTION+',','Slip #',',') B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SlipNr
1   195
2   112
3   222    <-- Notice multiple slips
3   999    <-- Notice multiple slips
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting Slip ID,

```
   declare @column varchar(200) = 'Packing Slip #234234295, UID = Pkg-15094-195'


   select substring(@column,charindex('#',@column)+1,charindex(',',@column)-charindex('#',@column)-1)
```